# classical sauce-making with induction cooktop

Tags: sauce, induction, aluminum-cookware, copper-cookware

In classical french sauce-making lined copper pots are preferred for their responsiveness. Can anyone tell me how induction-capable cookware such as Demeyere Atlantis sauciers or All-Clad D3 equivalents perform compared to lined copper with gas heat? It is really responsiveness more than evenesss of heat distribution that I am interested in.

Answer (score -1):

Cookware has nothing to do with sauces, you can make great sauces with whatever equipment  you have on hand, pan material (steel, aluminum, cooper...) or heat sources (gas, electric coils, ceramic induction or wood burning)

Most sauces need to be reduced to gain the most flavor, so responsiveness is not really an issue.